# Vuejs v-for re-build when update vuex object

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to vuejs I want re-build my v-for loop after update vuex object. see following example code.

```
<div class="row search-result-row" v-for="report in reports" :key="report">
   <p>{{ report.description }}</p>
</div>
```

here is my vuex object called globalReports. when I equal globalReports to reports it doesn't work.

```
computed: {
    updateReports: function() {
        return  this.reports = this.$store.state.globalReports;
    }
},
```

How can I do this without page reload?

Comment: It's unclear why `updateReports` is a computed property. Shouldn't it be in `methods`? It might be the case that `updateReports` is never referenced in the DOM, thereby never "computed" per se and does not execute. VueJS is reactive such that whenever `this.reports` is updated, your DOM will be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `{{updateReports}}`. Computed will not be executed util it is monitored or called,  just called `{{updateReports}}`

```
<div class="row search-result-row" v-for="report in reports" :key="report">
   <p>{{ report.description }}</p>
</div>
{{updateReports}}
```

And don't return anything just update/Assign value of `this.reports`

```
computed: {
    updateReports: function() {
        this.reports = this.$store.state.globalReports;
    }
},
```

Comment: Computed properties are just like getters . They are converted into normal properties of vue with this getter, so its better to return a value instead of assigning to a data property, and can just be used in templates like normal data properties. So `updateReports` can just return the state `globalReports` and used in as `v-for="report in updateReports"`

Answer (score 2):

by using `mapState`, you can map the value of `globalReports` to `reports` automatically.

Everytime `globalReports` change, `reports` gets updated automatically, and the rebuild will happen automatically when it gets updated.

```
<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed: mapState({
    reports: "globalReports"
  })
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Vuex is reactive so when you update the state,this change will affect all components where you use the state properties.To be more specific:

*I will show you an example:*

```
    //VUEX STORE
state: {
    property1
},
getters: {
    getProperty1(state) {
        return state.property1
    }
},
mutations: {
    setProperty1(state, payload) {
        state.property1 = payload
    }
},
actions: {
    changeProperty1({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setProperty1', payload)
    }
}
```

*And below is the component in which you interact with state*

```
<template>
    <p>this is from state of store {{ getProperty1 }</p>
    <input type="text" v-model="value"> 
    <button @click="changeState">Sumbit</button>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                value: ''
            }
        },
        computed: {
            getProperty1() {
                return this.$store.getters.getProperty1
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeState() {
                this.$store.dispatch('changeProperty1', this.value)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

*Getters are to get the state properties*
*Mutations to change the state properties*
*Actions to perform async code and then to call mutations to change the state*

For more please visit [vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/)